# How to pre-populate standard Account edit page fields from a VF page with custom controller?

Tags: apex, visualforce, slds

I have done this in the past, but it has been a while, and want to make sure if there are better ways of doing this.
I have a custom SLDS VF page with a button "Create Account". A user will populate a few fields on the VF page. When the button "Create Account" is clicked, I would like to grab the populated fields, and place them directly under the Standard Account Edit Page.
I know I can accomplish this, by passing the variables with an URL, but seeing where lightning is headed, that is no longer a good option.
Another solution I can think of, is creating another VF page that will serve as the page where the fields will be populated before I create the account.
Is there any other way of accomplishing my task?

Comment: Your button says "Create Account" but you say you want to pass to the standard Edit page.  That is not going to be possible unless your controller creates the account first.